# Python: Overriding (monkey patching) Class

Tags: python, class, overriding, monkeypatching, class-variables

I would like to override (patch) a Class on runtime. In my case I use gui2py and want t override some of it's functionality to support image in MenuItems but without changing the code of the final program.

i.e. I have

**overrides.py**

```
import gui,wx

# this is the tricky line    
gui.MenuItem.image = gui.component.InitSpec()

def menu__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    gui.menu.wx_DummyWindow.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
    wx.MenuItem.__init__(self, parentMenu=parent,id=kwargs['id'],text=kwargs['label'],kind=kwargs['style'])

    if self.GetKind() == wx.ITEM_SEPARATOR:
        self.parent.AppendSeparator()    
    else:
        self.SetHelp(kwargs['help'])
        # The next is added code
        img = kwargs.get("image")
        if img: 
            self.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(img))

        self.parent.AppendItem(self)

gui.menu.wx_MenuItem.__init__ =  menu__init__
```

**program.py**

```
from overrides import *

with gui.Window(name='win',  ):

    with gui.MenuBar(name='menu', ):
        with gui.Menu(label=u'File', name='file', ):
            gui.MenuItem(label=u'Quit', name='quit', image='quit.png' )

gui.main_loop()
```

This won't work.

However if I modify directly **gui/menu.py**

```
class MenuItem(Component):
    #add this line
    image = InitSpec()
```

Then it works

[Download This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6cj0bt8goezxfk/program.zip?dl=0) for a working demo

Comment: I guess the problem is you're patching `__init__` by just setting the function as a class attribute. You should turn it into an [instance method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType) before doing so.

Comment: Somehow the `__init__` works as expected, it's the class property _image_ that makes the change. If it is modified in the source directly or overriden

Comment: What's your error message then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after hours of research it seems like this is the correct way to add an attribute to a Class:

```
class _MenuItem(gui.MenuItem):
    image = gui.component.InitSpec()

# and then:        
gui.MenuItem = _MenuItem
```

Now it works fine

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `gui.MenuItem.image = ...` (unless `MenuItem`s meta class defines `__setattr__` and interferes in some way). I guess your solution works too in most cases, but an error message would be helpful to figure out why the former approach didn't work. Note that if `gui.MenuItem` had an attribute `image` it still has that same attribute. In the `__mro__` it's just the new `image` which resolves first for instances of `_MenuItem`. Also note that any type checks like `type(_MenuItem()) == OriginalMenuItem` will fail if an object has stored that reference before the patch.